# anyone have a better solution or method

Tags: c

I want to count if is the number of the row on the left group to make the conﬁguration acceptable by the procedures. Output -1 if there is no acceptable conﬁguration. the procedures is left a(X) middle b(x+1) and right c(x+2). does anyone have a better solution than mine?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int chairs,a,b,c,result;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &chairs,&a ,&b , &c);
    for(int i=1; i<=chairs; i++)
    {
        result= (a*(i)) + (b*(i+1)) + (c*(i+2));
        if(chairs == result)
        {
            printf("%d", i);
            break;
        }
        else if(i == chairs && chairs != result)
            printf("-1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please define your problem ? what is an acceptable configuration ? What are supposed to represent the 5 variables ?

Comment: Please show in your question what input you use and what output you get/expect.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a math problem.

`a * x + b * (x + 1) + c * (x + 2) = chair`

`a * x + b * x + b + c * x + 2 * c = chair`

`a * x + b * x + c * x = chair - b - 2 * c`

`x * (a + b + c) = chair - b - 2 * c`

`x = (chair - b - 2 * c) / (a + b + c)`

This can be solved in 1 operation. No solution if `a + b + c == 0`

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to a math question 
where

```
if ( (a+b+c) == 0)  return -1 ;
X = (Chairs - b - 2c) / (a+b+c) , Y = (Chairs - b - 2c) % (a+b+c)
if X > 0 && X <= Chairs && y == 0 
 return X ;
else 
return -1 ;
```

Comment: Don't you need a test  whether the divisor divides the divident evenly? E.g. `a=b=c=1 and Chairs=7` has no solution, while `a=b=c=1 and Chairs=6` has.

Comment: Maybe first check `a+b+c==0` before you calculate X and Y? And add some semicolons, round brackets and indentation?